# Iwasawa theory and an $M$ finitely generated $\Lambda _{\mathcal{O}}$ module

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory

A bit of context: I am currently self studying Iwasawa theory, and faced the following theorem:

> *Let $M$ be a finitely generated $\Lambda _{\mathcal{O}}$ module, then*
> $$M \sim \Lambda _{\mathcal{O}} ^\tau \oplus \left ( \bigoplus_{i=1} ^{s} \Lambda _{\mathcal{O}} / (\varpi
> ^{n_i})\right) \oplus \left ( \bigoplus_{j=1} ^{t} \Lambda _{\mathcal{O}} /  \left( f_j (T)^{m_j} \right)\right )$$

Note: $r, s, t, n_i$ and $m_j$ belong to $\Bbb{Z}$ and $ f_j (T)$ are distinguished and irreducible.

I am not sure how to prove it. I checked

> *L. Washington, Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields, Graduate Texts in
> Mathematics 83, Second Edition, Springer (1991)*

Specifically theorem 13.12 which I understood might be relevant? but still can't wrap my head around it. I'd appreciate hearing from you, wether it's an idea or some resources.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Theorem 13.12 is precisely this theorem when $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}_p$. What is your question?

Comment: Serre in [his Bourbaki talk](https://eudml.org/doc/109603) gave a different proof than in Washington.

Comment: Exactly this, I couldn't quite figure out why it holds. I am asking for an explanation if possible

Comment: thanks for the link! I'd check it.